# promise getting resolved even before .resolve() is called

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-promise

I have made a `LocationService` in angularjs

```
factory('LocationService', function ($q) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    var curPos = {};
    var resolved = false;

    return {
        getPosition : function (refresh) {
            if (!resolved || refresh) {
                navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (pos) {
                    curPos.curLat = pos.coords.latitude;
                    curPos.curLng = pos.coords.longitude;
                    resolved = true;
                    console.log("Resolve", curPos);
                    deferred.resolve(curPos);
                }, function (error) {
                    deferred.reject('Unable to get location: ' + error.message);
                }, {
                    enableHighAccuracy : true
                });
            } else {
                deferred.resolve(curPos);
            }
            return deferred.promise;
        }
    }
})
```

and using it like this

```
LocationService.getPosition(refresh).then(function (curPos) {
    console.log('then');
    var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(curPos.curLat, curPos.curLng);
    $scope.map.setCenter(latLng);
    $scope.map.setZoom(15);
});
```

First time it works fine, but when I click a button which calls `getPosition()`, it resolves even before the `LocationService` triggers `deferred.resolve()`. and I get the wrong result in the callback. But eventually after 2/3 seconds `getCurrentPosition` fires callback and the new value is set in `curPos`. Which I get for the next time.

The console prints `then` first and `Resolve` after 2/3 seconds.

I am not able to understand what's wrong here. Could someone guide a bit?

Comment: Are you trying to cache data? then you should use [$cacheFactory](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$cacheFactory)

Comment: Yes, I want to refresh user location only if I pass refresh explicitly.

Comment: Ok, will have a look at that. But that's not the problem here, is it?

Comment: Not sure, Move `var deferred = $q.defer();` inside your function

Comment: Can you post a fiddle that shows the issue?

Comment: OOO! Exactly, that was the problem. Why didn't I think of this. keeping it outside preserves its `resolve`d state from previous call, due to which `then` gets called immediately. Thanks a ton!!

Answer (score 0):

Your deferred gets declared as part of the service construction. Once your first call to getPosition finishes, that deferred gets resolved. You need to create and use a new deferred for each call to getPosition.